# Rest API: Is there any endpoint that provides dataset lineage info?

Tags: palantir-foundry, palantir-foundry-api

I was not able to find an endpoint that can provide information about datasets dependencies.

Example: I would like to same (but simplified) info as I do with lineage about Dataset A depending on B and C via Pipeline P / code repositori X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always see the network requests that populate the data in the `data lineage`.

If you expand the lineage downstream it uses the endpoint you can call using requests like this:

```
requests.post(f'{FOUNDRY_URL}/provenance/api/provenance/containers/graph',
              data={
                  'type': 'downstreamRequest',
                  'downstreamRequest': {
                      'downstreamResourceLabels': {},
                      'rootContainer': yourDatasetRid,
                      'upstreamResourceLabels': {}
                    })
```

And there is the equivalent for the upstream lineage.

Answer (score 1):

Matja solution worked. I also tried this one that reported incoming and outgoing links:

```
PalantirHostName = ...

datasetRid = ...

url = f"{PalantirHostName}/monocle/api/links"
request_body = {"resourceIdentifiers":[datasetRid],"branch":"master","fallbacks":[],"serviceTypeFilter":["BUILDGRAPH","EXTERNALGRAPH","PROVENANCEGRAPH","ONTOLOGYGRAPH"]}
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers,json=request_body)
```

Response:

> {"nodes":     [       {
> "resourceIdentifier":"ri.foundry.main.dataset.00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001"
> ,"links":[
> {
> "type":"datasetLink"
> ,"datasetLink":{
> "linkDirection":"INCOMING"
> ,"resourceIdentifier":"ri.foundry.main.dataset.00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002"
> ,"name":null,"inTrash":false
> }
> }
> ,{
> "type":"datasetLink"
> ,"datasetLink":{
> "linkDirection":"OUTGOING"
> ,"resourceIdentifier":"ri.foundry.main.dataset.00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000003"
> ,"name":null
> ,"inTrash":false
> }
> }           ]       }   ] }